Find all holomorphic functions $f=u+iv$ such that $g=u^2+iv^2$ is holomorphic
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a complex region. Find all holomorphic functions $f=u+iv$ in $\Omega$ such that $g=u^2+iv^2$ also be holomorphic in $\Omega$.
My attempt:
We know that Cauchy-Riemann equations for $f$ and $g$ must be satisfied in $\Omega$, i.e.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:CR-1}
  \Biggl\{
  \begin{aligned}
   u_x&=v_y,\\
   u_y&=-v_x,
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
and,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:CR-2}
  \Biggl\{
  \begin{aligned}
   2uu_x&=2vv_y\\
   2uu_y&=-2vv_x
  \end{aligned}
  \, \Longleftrightarrow \, \Biggl\{
  \begin{aligned}
   uu_x&=vv_y\\
   uu_y&=-vv_x
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
From which we get
\begin{equation}\label{eq:CR-3}
   \Biggl\{
  \begin{aligned}
   uu_x&=vu_x\\
   uu_y&=vu_y.
  \end{aligned}
   \, \Longleftrightarrow \,
  \Biggl\{
 \begin{aligned}
  (u-v)u_x&=0\\
  (u-v)u_y&=0
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I'm stuck in the last part because if I assume $u\neq v$, for all $z\in \Omega$ then I get that $f$ must be constant. Same case if I assume that $u=v$, for all $z\in \Omega$. But, what happens for example if $u\neq v$ for some $z\in \Omega$ and at the same time $u=v$ for other values in $\Omega$, or maybe this case is not possible?

$f$ being holomorphic a $z$ implies that the CR equations are satisfied on a neighborhood of $z$. The set $u=v$ has empty interior, so the only way the CR equations are satisfied on a neighborhood is if $u_x=u_y=0$, which implies that $f$ is (locally) constant

Now I have some idea, in the last case we have that $\Omega=A\cup B$, $A={z\in \Omega: u(z)=v(z)$ and $B=\Omega-A$. Then we will have $A\neq \varnothing$ and $B\neq \varnothing$. So, ${A,B}$ will be a separation of $\Omega$. Is this correct?

@SamBallas Yeah, but in this case I assuming that $f$ is holomorphic at each point $z\in \Omega$. Thus, CR equations are satisfied in all $\Omega$.

$$(u-v)u_x=0,(u-v)u_y=0\implies(u-v)f'(z)=0,\forall z\in\Omega\implies f'(z)\equiv0.$$

If $\nabla u = 0$ everywhere in $\Omega$ then $u$ is constant, and then by the Cauchy-Riemann equations also $\nabla v = 0$ everywhere $\Omega$, so similarly $v$ is constant. So it suffices to show $\nabla u = 0$ everywhere.
Suppose on the contrary $\nabla u(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$ at some $(x_0,y_0)$. Then by continuity there is a disk $D \subset \Omega$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ on which $\nabla u(x,y) \neq 0$. By what you've done $u = v$ on $D$. So taking $x$ and $y$ derivatives you have $u_x = v_x$ and $u_y = v_y$ on $D$. By the Cauchy-Riemann equations this means $u_x = -u_y$ and $u_y = u_x$ on $D$, which lead to $u_x = u_y = 0$ on $D$, contradicting that $\nabla u(x,y) \neq 0$ on $D$.
So we conclude that in fact $\nabla u = 0$ everywhere in $\Omega$ and $u$ is constant.

Nice  solution so far!

This is a short a elegant solution. Thanks a lot @Zarrax!

I'm assuming that $\Omega$ here is open and connected. In this case, for $f$ to be holomorphic, the CR equations must be satisfied on all of $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is open we have that $W=\Omega\backslash\{u=v\}$ is open in $\Omega$. This means that $u_x=u_y=0$ on the open set $W$, which implies that $f$ is locally constant $W$.
It turns out this implies that $f$ is actually constant. Assume that $W$ is not connected and $a$ and $b$ lie in different components of $W$. Connected and open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are path connected, so there is a path $\gamma$ connecting $a$ and $b$ in $\Omega$. The only time the value of $f$ along $\gamma$ can change is when it passes between connected components, but by continuity, the function has the same value on "adjacent" component, so the value of $f$ is constant along $\gamma$ and hence the same at any two points.
